# Github Pages not running Jekyll?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have forked Jekyll Now from https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now/commit/fb2f50ba6fab860134c416cc097707da159d8c6f to my mofomofo account on Github, and renamed the repo to mofomofo.github.io, but nothing's showing up there but a 404.

I have established that it is buildable and runnable by pulling it locally and running jekyll serve.

Does this work for anyone else?

Comment: Have you checked your repository settings? In the third section, he shows up a message like "Your site is published at http://mofomofo.github.io" when it is up and running.

Comment: It says "Your site is ready to be published at http://mofomofo.github.io."  Am I missing some next step to actually make it be published?

Answer (score 2):

Fast forward to '17, I ran into the same 'problem', initially the 'ready to be published' text was displayed, but after some clicking through the tabs (Options, Collaborators, ..) and coming back, it had changed. So maybe it just takes a bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works well even with the [github-pages gem](https://github.com/github/pages-gem).

I think this an already observed bug with [user repositories](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user--organization-pages), that appends when you rename a [project repository](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages) to an user repository.

I think you can try to :

1. delete mofomofo.github.io and recreate it from github interface
2. clone barryclark/jekyll-now locally
3. add mofomofo.github.io as a remote
4. push to mofomofo.github.io

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had not confirmed my email with Github.  As soon as I did then the page published.  How silly of me.  Thanks all for your help.